# Passing an ArrayList from one class to another in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm new to Java so my question is very basic. I have an array list in one class and I need to pass it to another class. How can I do this?

This is how I have initialized my ArrayList-

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File file = new File("C:\...");
        List<Character> aChars = new ArrayList<Character>();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        int c;
        while((c = reader.read()) != -1) {
            aChars.add((char) c);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my main class, how should I initialize another class such that I will be able to access the arrayList achars?

Comment: What do you mean by pass it to another class? If you're calling a function, doing `functioncall(aChars)` would work just fine assuming the function was written correctly

Comment: You really should provide more context, such as what is the class definition for the class you want to pass the array to?

Comment: You usually pass information as argument to a method in the other class. Or you get information from the other class by calling a method in it that returns the necessary data.

Comment: You could do this via a constructor or method parameter. But we cannot even begin to tell you any details given the lack of details in your question. Please improve it greatly. Please go through the [tour], the [help] and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: I've formatted your code for readability, but in the future I strongly recommend that you do this yourself, especially by giving your code proper indentations, usually 4 spaces per block, and making sure that all code on the same block is on the same indentation level. Formatting is very important because if your code is not in a standard accepted format, it's not very readable, and if it's not readable, it's not understandable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You ask:

> This is my main class, how should I initialize another class such that I will be able to access the arrayList achars?

First and foremost, by getting most of that code outside of the main method. Instead you will want to make object-oriented compliant classes, classes that have state (instance fields) and behaviors (non-static methods).

For instance, you could give your class a method that reads from a file and returns the ArrayList of interest:

```
public List<Character> getCharsFromFile(File file) {
    List<Character> aChars = new ArrayList<Character>();

    //.... code that reads form the file and places data into aChars

    return aChars;
}
```

and then later in your program you could call this method, passing in the file when needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the other class to have access to aChars, you can add a setter.  If you require the other class to have access to aChars, you should add it to the constructor.

**Requires the List**

```
Class MyClass {
    private List<Character> mChars;

    // note how you cannot construct MyClass without providing the array
    public MyClass( List<Character> chars ) {
        mChars = chars;
        if ( mChars == null ) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("chars cannot be null");
        }
    }

    private void doStuff() {
        // now you can safely use the array is available (though maybe empty)
        for( Character c : mChars ) {
            System.out.println(c);
        }
    }
}
```

**Does not require the List**

```
Class MyClass {
    private List<Character> mChars;

    // note how the constructor does not require the array
    public MyClass() {
    }

    public void setChars( List<Character> chars ) {
        mChars = chars;
    }

    // notice we had to do a null check
    private void doStuff() {
        if ( mChars != null ) {
            // now you can safely use the array is available (though maybe empty)
            for( Character c : mChars ) {
                System.out.println(c);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Notice the difference between them is whether or not the array is required for use of the class.